# Python shorthand using only if, excluding the else part

Tags: python

Was using the shorthand for if/else statements, and that works fine by the way.

```
found_target = True if qo_cplId == cpl_id else False
```

Was trying to omit the else part but got error!

```
found_target = True if aircraft_identifier == qo_squawk
```

Comment: What do you want to be the result if `aircraft_identifier` is not equal to `qo_squawk`?

Comment: Then it just passes through and does not modify the value of the found_target variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you can use:

```
found_target = (qo_cplId == cpl_id)
```

It gives you the same boolean output though, True/False.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't actually answer the question stated.

Comment: @JonB: This will not do what you said you wanted it to do.

Answer (score 3):

No, the `else` part cannot be omitted, because an expression **always** has to produce a value, and a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) is no exception here. Without the `else`, what would `found_target` be set to otherwise?

If you only want to set `found_target` if the condition is true, just use a regular `if` *statement*:

```
if aircraft_identifier == qo_squawk:
    found_target = True
```

Note that the `==` comparison operator already produces a boolean value, so the first expression can be simplified to:

```
found_target = qo_cplId == cpl_id
```

Comment: "Without the else, what would `found_target` be set to otherwise?"

Itself -- left unchanged. Of course the 'else' part of the ternary expression is mandatory, not optional, but it's easy to see what the shorthand would have to mean: `x = a if p` would have the very same semantics as `x = a if p else x`. Of course, `x` has to be already defined. *However* this only makes sense if the expression is the RHS of an assignment, whereas it can occur in many other contexts, where the only sensible default value would be `None` . In short, it would be a *horrible* confusing construct.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the conditional expression (the short-hand you are talking about) without an `else`.

Every expression in python needs to return something , this includes the conditional expression . But without the `else` part Python would not know what to return in case when the condition fails.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use a [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) here but that’s simply not how it works. The syntax there requires the use of `else`. It’s more like the ternary `?:` operator in other languages.

If you want to execute a statement conditionally, you have to use a normal if block:

```
if aircraft_identifier == qo_squawk:
    found_target = True
```

You can put that in a single line here (not recommended though)

```
if aircraft_identifier == qo_squawk: found_target = True
```

---

If you also want to change `found_target` to `False` if the condition is not true, then you best assign the result to the variable directly:

```
found_target = aircraft_identifier == qo_squawk
```

And if you don’t want to overwrite `found_target`’s old value if the condition is not true, you can also do the following using Python’s `or` operator:

```
found_target = aircraft_identifier == qo_squawk or found_target
```

This is then equivalent to the if statement above.